# Visual Basics Excel txt input file

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

Line "Input #1, Numbers(Row, Column)" is giving me a runtime bug 9. Any ideas? The comments in the code explain what's supposed to happen.

```
Sub InputImage()
'brings a text file to the workbook

Dim Row As Long, Column As Long, Nrow As Long, Ncolumn As Long

    Call MsgBox("Navigate to a folder that contains the file image.txt in the 00_18 folder")
    '   The next statement will open a dialogue box that will let
    '   the user navigate to any folder on their system
    Call Application.GetOpenFilename
Open "image.txt" For Input As #1

Dim Buffer As String
Line Input #1, Buffer 'read a whole line of characters from
    'file #1 into the string variable buffer

Line Input #1, Buffer
Input #1, Buffer, Nrow
Input #1, Buffer, Ncolumn

Dim Numbers(1 To 4, 1 To 4) As Long
For Row = 1 To Nrow
    For Column = 1 To Ncolumn
        Input #1, Numbers(Row, Column)
    Next Column
Next Row

Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the values of Row and Column when the error occurs?

Comment: Error 9 Subscript out of range means your array and your data in the text file are not friends yet :-). It will be helpfull if you could post the data you want to read from the file image.txt to the array Numbers.

Comment: you know you could read your text file as a query using ADO if it's delimited - look at [MSDN Scripting Clinic: Much ADO About Text Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx)

Comment: As @Philip says, delimited or fixed format.

Comment: You can also quite simply open a text file: `Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="Z:\Docs\Document1.txt", Origin:=xlMSDOS, _
        StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
Option Base 1
Sub InputImage()
'brings a text file to the workbook
    Dim j As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim Row As Long, Column As Long, Nrow As Long, Ncolumn As Long

    Call MsgBox("Navigate to a folder that contains the file image.txt in the 00_18 folder")
    '   The next statement will open a dialogue box that will let
    '   the user navigate to any folder on their system
    Call Application.GetOpenFilename


    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim DataLine As String

    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open "image.txt" For Input As #FileNum


    j = 1
    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine    ' read in data 1 line at a time
        ' decide what to do with dataline,
        ' depending on what processing you need to do for each case
        'you can use split function to split DataLine with required delimiter which will return you an array.
        a = Split(DataLine, vbTab)

        For i = 1 To UBound(a)
            Cells(j, i).Value = a(i)
        Next
        j = j + 1
    Wend


End Sub
```

Assuming your image.txt is like below image.

[image]